# ECS Fargate task keeps failing due to permission issues - jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I have a ECS task that keeps failing due to the following error logs:

touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?

Details:
policy for task has full ecs, efs permissions
efs and ec2 container are on same subnet, 2049 inbound rule
access point for efs is set up (1000 : 1000 , 1000 : 1000 (777))

Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Jenkins base image
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.414.2-jdk11

USER root

# Create or set up your Jenkins home directory
RUN mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home

# Set ownership to the Jenkins user
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/jenkins_home
RUN chmod 600 /var/jenkins_home
RUN chmod 755 /var/jenkins_home

# Install required dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release python3-pip

# Configure Docker repository for the target architecture (e.g., amd64)
RUN curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64 \
  signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc] \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
USER jenkins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean:1.25.3 docker-workflow:1.28"
```

```
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "jenkins-volume",
                    "containerPath": "/var/jenkins_home",
                    "readOnly": false
                }
            ],
```

I've tried changing my dockerfile to run as root and it still errors.